# Problems using Sync Framework to Sync local MSSQL database to hosted MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a problem. I want to use the Sync Framework to sync my local MSSQL db to hosted MySQL db, but I have problems, since my code at the moment uses `SqlConnection`, but I have no idea how to be able to make the `serverConn` a MySqlConnection.

My code:

AppConnectionFactory.cs:

```
public class AppConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory _provider;
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly string _name;

    public AppConnectionFactory(string connectionName)
    {
        if (connectionName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionName");

        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName];
        if (connStr == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(string.Format("Failed to find the connection named {0} in App.config",connectionName));

        _name = connStr.ProviderName;
        _provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connStr.ProviderName);
        _connectionString = connStr.ConnectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection Create()
    {
        var connection = _provider.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

DbSync.cs:

```
public class DbSync
{
    private readonly IConnectionFactory _serverConn;
    private readonly IConnectionFactory _clientConn;
    private readonly string _sScope = "SmartFridgeScope";

    public DbSync(IConnectionFactory serverConn, IConnectionFactory clientConn)
    {
        _serverConn = serverConn;
        _clientConn = clientConn;
    }

    public void ProvisionServer()
    {
        var serverConn = (SqlConnection)_serverConn.Create();
        var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn);

        if (serverProvision.ScopeExists(_sScope)) return;

        var scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(_sScope);

        var listDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("List", serverConn);
        scopeDesc.Tables.Add(listDesc);
        var itemDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Item", serverConn);
        scopeDesc.Tables.Add(itemDesc);
        var listItemDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("ListItem",
            serverConn);

        scopeDesc.Tables.Add(listItemDesc);

        serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc);
        serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.CreateOrUseExisting);
        serverProvision.Apply();
    }

    public void ProvisionClient()
    {
        var clientConn = (SqlConnection)_clientConn.Create();
        var serverConn = (SqlConnection)_serverConn.Create();

        var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn);
        if (clientProvision.ScopeExists(_sScope)) return;

        var scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(_sScope, serverConn);
        clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc);
        clientProvision.Apply();
    }

    public void Sync()
    {
        var clientConn = (SqlConnection)_clientConn.Create();
        var serverConn = (SqlConnection)_serverConn.Create();

        var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
        {
            LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(_sScope, clientConn),
            RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(_sScope, serverConn),
            Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload
        };

        syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me be able to use a MySqlConnection instead of a SqlConnection?

Tell me if I need to explain more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no built in provider for MySQL.  You will have to write your own implementation.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807291(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Hmm, I have no clue how to.

Comment: it's not an easy process, and definitely more than can be described in one answer here.  That article I linked has the general steps.

Comment: Thanks @Claies, you lead me to a link I did not visit yet, which may be helpful in accomplishing this task (somehow I did not see such link before in my searches).